# How to add a disk back to sysfs after deleting it

Tags: filesystems, disk, sysfs

A fs disk failure was simulated by:

```sh
  echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/delete
```

which removes it from /dev dir. What is the procedure of adding it back?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
#/bin/bash
# ReScan all SCSI/SATA Hosts
for SHOST in /sys/class/scsi_host/host*; do
    echo -n "Scanning ${SHOST##*/}..."
    echo "- - -" > ${SHOST}/scan
    echo Done
done
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/882835/add-a-scsi-disk-on-linux-without-rebooting

Comment: This is a case where "tee" shines. `echo "- - -" | tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan` :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I removed the disks, which were connected by scsi. Command:

```
rescan-scsi-bus.sh
```

helped me get back all deleted drives.